more details on customBatchSizeValue in VsTest task
I have a below VsTest task in my azure pipeline that runs in a single agent. It runs more than 5 thousand tests. Does someone knows what exactly the 'customBatchSizeValue' means ? I know the tests are grouped as batches, each containing 800 test cases and for every batch, it generates a separate trx file and a test run. My question is: do the 800 test cases in every batch run in parallel as well ? How does it changes when tests are UI & non-UI ?
I already referred this MS doc on VsTest, but doesn't seem to be detailed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Run UI tests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\UITest.dll'
    searchFolder: '$(TargetDir)\UITest'
    vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
    runSettingsFile: '$(TargetDir)\UITest.pipeline.runsettings'
    pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'C:\Temp\TestAdapter'
    runTestsInIsolation: false
    batchingBasedOnAgentsOption: customBatchSize
    customBatchSizeValue: 800
    testRunTitle: 'UITest from Directory (1)'
    platform: x64
    failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
    rerunFailedTests: true
  continueOnError: true
  timeoutInMinutes: 180


See Run tests in parallel using the Visual Studio Test task, in particular Massively parallel testing by combining parallel pipeline jobs with parallel test execution.

My job/task runs on a single agent. In this case, what is the relevance of setting the customBatchSizeValue to 800? Do the tests in each batch run in parallel at the same time, or do the tests run one by one within each batch?

The answer to your question is in the links I provided. It also depends on the tests you're running, if the library supports parallelism or not, etc. Just try a few things and see how it goes :-) You can answer your own question with your conclusions

Oh and you might take a look into the runInParallel option of the VSTest@2 task as well.

In Visual Studio test task, the customBatchSizeValue value is used to set the test slices size.
To let the test slices to run in parallel, you need to create multiple agents on single or multiple machines. This is required.
Refer to this doc: Massively parallel testing by combining parallel pipeline jobs with parallel test execution

Parallelism offered by the Visual Studio Test (VSTest) task. The VSTest task supports running tests in parallel across multiple agents (or machines). Test slices are created, and each agent executes one slice at a time. The three different slicing strategies, when combined with the parallelism offered by the test platform and test framework

From your comment, you only have one single agent. In this case, the test slices will not run parallel. They will run one by one within each test slices.
To use the option: customBatchSizeValue  to reduce the test time, you need to create multiple agents and define it in the Pipeline.
For example:
Pool: AgentPool

jobs:
- job: ParallelTesting
  strategy:
    parallel: 5

For the option: runInParallel in Vstest task, when you enable the option and customBatchSizeValue in the VS Test task, the test slices on each machine will run in parallel and the tests in test slices will run in parallel too.
